# $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation() leading to "No response defined !" error

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

[My understanding](https://medium.com/@adamzerner/how-does-httpbackend-work-bd6af4eeb849) of [$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) is that it basically says "Make sure all of the requests that are `$httpBackend.expect()`-ed by your tests were made by your code. If any of them weren’t, I’ll throw an exception."

1) This seems redundant. Isn't it the case that the corresponding `$httpBackend.expect()` would fail, and thus alert you?

2) I'm getting a `No response defined !` error when I use `$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()`. The error goes away and my test passes when I remove `$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()`. Why would this be?

[image]

`admin.controller.spec.js:14` refers to the `$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()` call.

**admin.controller.spec.js**

```
describe('AdminController', function() {
  var AdminController, scope, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(module('mean-starter'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _$httpBackend_) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    AdminController = $controller('AdminController', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    // $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('gets users', function() {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/users');
  });
});
```

**admin.controller.js**

```
angular
  .module('mean-starter')
  .controller('AdminController', AdminController);

function AdminController(User, Auth, $state) {
  var vm = this;
  User
    .list()
    .success(function(data) {
      vm.users = data;
    })
    .error(function() {
      console.log('Problem getting users.');
    });

  vm.delete = function(id) {
    User
      .delete(id)
      .success(function(data) {
        if (Auth.getCurrentUser()._id === id) Auth.logout(); // deleting yourself
        else $state.reload();
      })
      .error(function() {
        console.log('Problem deleting user.');
      });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message clearly states the problem - You need to define the expected response before you can verify that the expectation has been satisfied.

Change

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('/users');
```

to

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('/users').respond([{
  //Response object or array
}]);
```

Comment: I'm still investigating but check out `it('should fetch authentication token', function() {
     $httpBackend.expectGET('/auth.py');
     var controller = createController();
     $httpBackend.flush();
   });
` from [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend). It seems that you don't always need a `.respond`. If so, why is it complaining about my code?